# Python indexing using another array/list

Tags: python

Sorry if the question is already answered. I couldn't figure out a term to use to search this.

I have a bunch of list coordinates in a list, like the one below.

```
coordinate = [[0,0,0,0], [1,1,1,1,]]
```

I have to use this to change a value in an array for numpy. (I didn't use numpy for the title because it can be used for normal lists too)

To change a value in numpy I have to run

```
array[0,0,0,0]=value
```

How do I make `array[0,0,0,0]` from `array` and `[0,0,0,0]`? I know I how to use strings to make a string that looks like that, but can I use that string to run a function for slice an index?

Comment: Sorry but I am confused with your question? What are you trying to change? Can you provide more details along with some examples in your question?

Comment: I'm trying to make a command ```array[0,0,0,0]``` by using a string ```array``` and a list ```[0,0,0,0]```

Comment: Thats not very easy. You can use `eval` but I DONT recommend it. You could probably use tuple unpacking with numpy such as: `array[*coordinate[0]] = value`. There is no really "safe" way to turn strings into raw syntax.

Comment: Convert the index list to a tuple: `array[tuple(coordinate[0])]`

Comment: @PaulPanzer This is mind blowing! Thank you!

Comment: Please put your actual inputs. There is no need for ambiguity

Comment: Why does this the title mention strings? I don't see what they have to do with this question.

Comment: Also, a brief search of SO shows that this question has already been asked, and answered, multiple times.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile The question mentions strings because he's trying to turn strings into raw syntax.

Comment: @John how can you tell that he's doing that, has he edited the question? His indexes are inside of a nested list of ints, I can't see where strings actually play a role.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile his response to the first comment: "I'm trying to make a command array[0,0,0,0] by using a string array and a list [0,0,0,0]"

Comment: @John yes, but from looking at his post it seems quite clear to me that that is not what he is actually trying to do, he just misspoke.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile It's not clear to me why we should disregard what little clarification he's provided.  The question should definitely be edited to make it more clear but why do you think he's attempting to do something other than the thing he clearly stated he was attempting to do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200922/discussion-between-alexander-cecile-and-john).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With test array:

```
In [163]: arr = np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)
```

selecting an item:

```
In [168]: arr[0,1,2]                                                            
Out[168]: 6
```

selecting the same item with a index list:

```
In [169]: idx = [0,1,2]                                                         
In [170]: arr[tuple(idx)]                                                       
Out[170]: 6
```

`arr[0,1,2]` is implicitly `arr[(1,2,3)]`.  The Python interpreter passes those comma separated index numbers as a tuple to the array's `__getitem__` method.

This multidimensional indexing does not work with lists.

```
In [171]: alist = arr.tolist()                                                  
In [172]: alist[0][1][2]                                                        
Out[172]: 6
```

For several points:

```
In [180]: idx = np.array([[0,1,2],[1,2,3]])                                     
In [181]: idx                                                                   
Out[181]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 3]])
In [182]: tuple(idx.T)                                                          
Out[182]: (array([0, 1]), array([1, 2]), array([2, 3]))
In [183]: arr[tuple(idx.T)]                                                     
Out[183]: array([ 6, 23])
```

In effect I am passing each column of `idx` as an indexing array (for each dimension).